# Custom Address Fields

Tags: visualforce, address

I have a requirement to add new address field  when u click on Add new Address button on Vf page.I can show up new address field but I am running out of fields(800) on object.

So I want to create a new address object to store the address record and relate to parent object.But I want to use this address object with multiple parent objects.Is there a way to create a new Address object and relate to multiple objects without creating multiple lookup fields

Its just like  **Related To** field on Task or Event

I think something like this [app exchange product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008YIeMEAW) also works for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [junction object](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&language=en_US). However, note that junction objects are rather [expensive in data storage](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gPAZAA2).